# fluidrow() not showing on one row with toc

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I have a shiny app in an rmarkdown document with a table of contents, but fluidrow() elements that should be on row are no longer one row once the toc is present, irrespective of the value of th column width:

````
---
title: "Test column with toc"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
runtime: shiny
---

## headline

Fluidrow won't be in one row:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(2,
sliderInput(
"obs",
"Number of observations:",
min = 1,
max = 1000,
value = 500,
width = "20%"
)
),
column(2,
plotOutput("distPlot", width = "60%"))))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
hist(rnorm(input$obs))
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on window size, columns will by default change to stacked at a width of 768px, using class `col-sm-2`. The is a bootstrap class (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options).  However, if you want different behaviour, you could use a div and give it the class `col-xs-2` so to divide the screen in half it would be `div( class = "col-xs-6", ...)`

Here is an example of what you could do:

````
Fluidrow won't be in one row:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    div( class = "col-xs-6",
      sliderInput(
        "obs",
        "Number of observations:",
        min = 1,
        max = 1000,
        value = 500,
        width = "50%"
      )
    ),
    div( class = "col-xs-6",
      plotOutput("distPlot", width = "100%")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


```
````

Also note that the widths of the plot and slider are relative to there column.